# $.ajax.load() triggers callback before images are loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, callback

Why does ajax `load()` triggers callback before all images are fully loaded.

```
$(element).load("url #id", function()
{
    $(this).fadeIn();
})
```

When I load data, `element` fades in and I see how images are drawn slowly on my screen... is it that image is loaded but computer is slow?

What should I do to show content after it's fully loaded?

Comment: Because it isn't meant to wait until content is loaded, it just performs an ajax request and gets the content and appends it. After it is appended, the success is called, after which the images begin to load.

Comment: the callback means Just the returned HTML is here 
You need to make extra work to make this done

Comment: @Sedz But then why $(window).load() callback is triggered when all content is fully loaded?

Comment: jQuery has a [load() event handler](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/) and a [load() ajax function](http://api.jquery.com/load/) that are two different things. As allready stated above your callback is for the ajax request.

Comment: @MarcelGwerder thank you for clearing that up, but what should be my solution here?

Comment: You could try to add the load event handler to the images and then fade the element in there. `$('img', element).on('load', function() { $(element).fadeIn()});` I'm not sure if that works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`$(element).load` will load content into your `element`, but then you can find all images and attach a load callback on them to determine when all images have been loaded. However, this is not very reliable since the `load` event on images might never fire for various reasons. In some browsers, the `load` event will be synchronous when the image is cached, so it will fire before we even attached an event handler on the image. For that reason, if images are not loaded after 5 seconds, we show the `element` anyway.

```
$(element).load("url #id", function () {
    var $self = $(this),
        $images = $self.find('img'),
        imgCount = $images.length,
        loadedCount = 0;

    $images.on('load', function () {
        if (++loadedCount === imgCount) {
            $self.fadeIn();
            $(this).off('load');
        }
    });

    setTimeout(function () {
        if (loadedCount !== imgCount) {
            $self.fadeIn();
            $images.off('load');
        }
    }, 5000);
});
```

Comment: @skmasq, No problem, I havent tested myself ;) You can adjust the 5 seconds timeout to whatever you want that is more suitable.

Comment: I just think, that your load isn't assigned correctly, I would use `.each()` to assign `.load()` but I will let you know how it works.

Comment: @skmasq, jQuery does the iteration automatically already, however you might prefer to use `on('load')` to avoid confusion with the other `load` function call that loads content instead of attaching an event handler.

Answer (score 0):

From the [jQuery documentation](http://api.jquery.com/load-event/):

> **Caveats of the load event when used with images**
>
> A common challenge developers attempt to solve using the .load()
>   shortcut is to execute a function when an image (or collection of
>   images) have completely loaded. There are several known caveats with
>   this that should be noted. These are:
>
> 1. It doesn't work consistently nor reliably cross-browser
> 2. It doesn't fire correctly in WebKit if the image src is set to the
>      same src as before
> 3. It doesn't correctly bubble up the DOM tree
> 4. Can cease to fire for images that already live in the browser's
>      cache

In the same documentation they offer a soultion to display graphics when they are loaded.

You can chech for the `height` property to be what it needs to be before displaying the image, since it will change size only when it has really been loaded (only if you did not specify it in the css though).

Comment: The method the OP uses seems to be the Ajax `load` method (http://api.jquery.com/load/), not the `load` *event* method.

Comment: I added a solution from the same documentation

Comment: False. It will show full height when image is started to load. It might load line by line 30 seconds, just tested that on my Virtual Box.